# i can't pass and get the variable in scalate template

Tags: spring-mvc, scalate

As suggested I'm asking new question in new topic.

I have a problem with passing an argument to my scalate template (.ssp)

Below my controller and my template

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    User user = new User("Dawid", "Pacholczyk");

    ModelAndView template = new ModelAndView("defaultTemplate");
    template.addObject("user", user);

    return template;
}
```

---

```
<%@ val bar: String = "this is the default value" %>
<% attributes("title") = "This is the custom title" %>
<%@ var user: User %>
 <p>Hi ${user.name},</p>
#do(layout("layouts/default.ssp"))
this is some template output...
<br />
${bar}
#end
```

Now I get exception:

```
    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is    org.fusesource.scalate.CompilerException: Compilation failed:
    /WEB-INF/scalate/defaultTemplate.ssp:3.13 error: not found: type User


            ^

    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Now I don't know what to do. I'll add that when I delete `<%@ var user: User %>` everything works great

What to do ?

Comment: @ebaxt you`re my idol !! Import works great (the first one). Rly big big thanks

Comment: Glad to help. I added an answer for further reference ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import user before you can use it.

```
<% import somePackage.User %>
```